# What is difference between python mock and magic mock?

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock, magicmock

What is difference between python mock and magic mock, because I could see

```
>>> dir(Mock()) == dir(MagicMock())
True
```

when to use mock obj & when to use MagicMock obj??

Answer (score 0):

`MagicMock is a subclass of Mock with default implementations of many magic methods. You can use MagicMock without having to configure the magic methods yourself.`

I suppose the code above is to affect most of magic methods to your mock automatically

check this guide it may help you [Magic Methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html)

and official doc https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: What are those many magic methods? that I can use with out configuring?